# Make index.html default, but allow index.php to be visited if typed in

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have the following line in my .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Everytime I go to index.php it takes me to index.html. Is it possible to allow for both, but leave index.html the default for users visiting www.domain.com?

Comment: Do both `index.html` and `index.php` exist, or just one?

Comment: They both exist. Are you saying my .htaccess file should allow me to visit both?

Comment: Shouln't you have only `index.html` in `DirectoryIndex`? Then it would be the default for `example.com`. The other file should be available at `example.com/index.php`.

Comment: It actually redirects you to index.html even though index.php exists?  There some other configuration interfering then.  Perhaps a rewrite rule gone awry or something?

Comment: I will suggest you to look into your `index.php` and make sure it is not redirecting you to `/` using some `header` function.

Comment: I think it might be, it's a Wordpress install afterall.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

By default, the DirectoryIndex is set to:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm default.htm index.php index.php3 index.phtml index.php5 index.shtml mwindex.phtml
```

Apache will look for each of the above files, in order, and serve the first one it finds when a visitor requests just a directory. If the webserver finds no files in the current directory that match names in the DirectoryIndex directive, then a directory listing will be displayed to the browser, showing all files in the current directory.

The order should be `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php` // default is index.html

**Reference:** [Here](http://support.modwest.com/content/1/147/en/how-can-i-show-a-default-page-other-than-indexhtml.html).

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll remove the .htaccess file tonight and see if this fixes my issue. I thought it seemed a bit odd as it's never happened to any of my websites before this.

Answer (score 19):

If you're using WordPress, there is now a filter hook to resolve this:

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

(Put this in your theme's `functions.php`)

This tells WordPress to not redirect `index.php` back to the root page, but to sit where it is. That way, `index.html` can be assigned to be the default page in `.htaccess` and can work alongside `index.php`.

Comment: That's  a life saver!!

Answer (score 6):

I agree with @TheAlpha's accepted answer, Apache reads the DirectoryIndex target files from left to right , if the first file exists ,apche serves it and if it doesnt then the next file is served as an index for the directory. So if you have the following Directive :

```
DirectoryIndex file1.html file2.html
```

Apache will serve /file.html as index ,You will need to change the order of files  if you want to set /file2.html as index

```
DirectoryIndex file2.html file1.html
```

You can also set index file using a RewriteRule

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [L]
```

RewriteRule above will rewrite your homepage to /index.html the rewriting happens internally so http://example.com/ would show you the contents ofindex.html .

Answer (score 5):

> DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm default.htm index.php index.php3
>   index.phtml index.php5 index.shtml mwindex.phtml

**it doesn't has any means?**
you may be just need to add like this!

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
</IfModule>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Hi,**

Well, I have tried the methods mentioned above! it's working yes, but not exactly the way I wanted. I wanted to **redirect the default page extension** to the main domain with our further action.

**Here how I do that...**

```
# Accesible Index Page
<IfModule dir_module>
 DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.(html|htm|php|php3|php5|shtml|phtml) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^index\.html|htm|php|php3|php5|shtml|phtml$ / [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The above code simply captures any index.* and redirect it to the main domain.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Put these two lines at the top of your .htaccess file. It will show .html in the URL for your .php pages.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1.html%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Use this for showing .php in URL for your .html pages.

Comment: This looks nifty but not quite what I was after I'm afraid.