# default to index.html but allow user to type to index.php and get the php page

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I'm busy building a Wordpress website for a client. I've developed the site off-line and would now like to upload it to the live server to show the client what I've done so far. I want to keep the "Under Construction" html page I've create as the default when browsing to the site but if you type in www.sitename.com/index.php I want the actual site to be displayed.

I don't want to use an "under construction" plugin as I don't want the user to have to enter any form of username or password to gain access to the site.

I have tried: *DirectoryIndex index.htm* but as soon as I browse to index.php it flips me back to the index.htm page.

I've had a look here:
[Make index.html default, but allow index.php to be visited if typed in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002439/make-index-html-default-but-allow-index-php-to-be-visited-if-typed-in)
but unless I'm missing it, there's no real conclusion.

My development machine runs Windows 8 with XAMPP.

Comment: Why don't you put your preview in a directory?

Comment: The question you linked to seems to solve it (it's the order they're placed, just read the answer). Which part there did not work for you?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I tried the accepted answer but all that happens is when I request index.php I simply get flipped back to index.html

Comment: @kingkero, I want to be able to just remove the html file when the site is ready to go live and not have to redirect or move the site afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your `.htaccess` file to redirect the user to `index.html` when he types the domain name, if he especially types `index.php`, he will be able to get on that page

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Alien. I tried adding the line you suggested but I'm still getting the same result. I've never worked with .htaccess files before so I'm not too sure I'm doing it right. Here's what the index.php file looks like:
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
I've tried replacing the first RewiteRule with your suggestion, I've tried putting it before the Wordpress section, and also on it's own.

Comment: @robhob You need to place that line in your `.htaccess` file

Comment: If I use your code:
`RewriteRule ^$ index.html [R=301,L]`
index.php loads automatically and if I then type index.html I get the html page. The problem is, I need it to work the other way around - I need it to default to the html page and only go to the php when it is explicitly entered.

Comment: @robhob Do your htaccess contains some rules like directory index?

Comment: All I have in the .htaccess file is your one line of code:
`RewriteRule ^$ index.html [R=301,L]`
Am I right in assuming that I don't need to restart Apache every time I edit this file?

Comment: @robhob Nope, you are not editing any server config file so you don't need to restart, but this is the way I recently did in my project and it worked quiet well, the usser gets redirected to .html, he needs to type .php to get to main page

Comment: Would it make any difference that I'm running this on my local machine and using it's IP address? Do I need `RewriteEngine On` before you line of code?

Comment: @robhob You don't need rewrite engine, also you should try this online, just use a demo page, html and host it online and have another php page, am sure this will work

Comment: I tried as you suggested and tested it on my live site but my index.htm then comes up as not found :(

Comment: @robhob Hehe you need to figure out things now

Comment: Okay. Found this on wordpress forums:[Disable Canonical URL Redirection](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-can-i-turn-off-wordpress-indexphp-redirect-to-domain-root?replies=18) which solved my problem. Thanks for all your time and trouble.