# Writing htaccess to load index.html and index.php in the same directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a bit of a complicated situation. I'm working on a landing page with an enter link (index.php). The landing page is index.html, however, I am using wordpress rewrite rules to load the entire site as if it were in the index directory.

The wordpress files are in /wordpress/, whereas the site when loaded from mydomain.com loads each page without /wordpress/.

The problem is, when the mydomain.com is loaded, by default index.html is loaded. The link contains an index.php href, but when clicked it brings me back to index.html. I know why it does this, but not sure how to, or if it's even possible to make a rewrite rule to aid this situation.

Here's my htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Provide more information about how you define your href for index.php

Comment: @OlegGryb Do you mean <a href="index.php">link</a> ?

Comment: Yep and I don't understand why it redirects back to index.html when you click on this link. Since you wrote that you do understand, probably you can explain.

Comment: I wouldn't have asked the community if I didn't have this problem. I'm not sure why either, though it probably does come from the line RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]. I do believe that it comes from trying to call an index that is rewritten as the default directory, basically to remove /wordpress/ from the path when called.

Comment: That rule could explain why it gets redirected to index.php, but I still don't understand how it can be redirected back to index.html. Probably you should provide more details about index.html page. Probably something is wrong with the 'href'

Comment: Here is my theory. When you have just "index.php" in your href and index.html is located in '/', web server will search for index.php in '/' as well. Theoretically, it can lead to 404 error, but since I don't know other rules, maybe 404 handler just redirects it to index.html again. Anyway, if your index.html is really in '/' as I've assumed, try to use /wordpress/index.php in href instead of index.php.

Comment: No, I don't have any reason to believe there's something wrong with the href. I'm using wordpress to load the site as if it were in the index directory, whereas it's actually in the directory /wordpress/. There are two htaccess files with the same content that I posted above. 

I do believe it's because by default, the server loads index.html, index.php, etc., but since the rules require it to remove /wordpress/, when you visit index.php from index.html, it defaults back to index.html and doesn't permit index.php from being accessed due to the conflicting nature.

Comment: "the rules require it to remove /wordpress/" - what rules are you referring to? Where index.html is located? Is it in "/" or is it in "/wordpress" ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be helpful to you.

[Make index.html default, but allow index.php to be visited if typed in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002439/make-index-html-default-but-allow-index-php-to-be-visited-if-typed-in)

DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm default.htm index.php index.php3 index.phtml index.php5 index.shtml mwindex.phtml