# DirectoryIndex: Prioritize index.html, but index.php should also work

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress installation on which I want to work currently. The visitor should just see a static index.html when he visits the site, but I will still enter domain.com/index.php in the browser and the normal WP site should load.

I changed my .htaccess to:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

But now the index.html is always loaded, even when I type domain.com/index.php in the browser. How can I set the index.html as the default but can still reach the index.php?

Thanks.

Comment: When you type domain.com/index/.php , then the index.php get removed from the url after the page loads?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002439/make-index-html-default-but-allow-index-php-to-be-visited-if-typed-in