# .htaccess Rewrite .html - One page keeps giving 403 Forbidden error

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to hide the .html extensions of my website
I use the following code below I found on StackOverflow to do this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works on every page (about.html, contact.html are all hidden) expect blog.html

So basically, mydomain.com/blog gives me the following error;

```
You don't have permission to access /blog/ on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

This is an HTML file that in the root folder, just like contact and about. but haves links from a subfolder (which contains blog page HTML). So I'm guessing the issue is coming from that?

Also as a side note, if I go directly to a blog post (mydomain.com/blog/post1.html) it works and hides the .html

I searched a lot but couldn't find a solution. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

```
    My document order

 - .htaccess
 - about.html
 - blog.html [only file that gives 403 error]
 - blog (folder)
      - post1.html
      - post2.html
```

Comment: You are having a directory slash related issue. Turn off the directory slash using the following line in htaccess **DirectorySlash off**

Answer (score 1):

First; the error occurs because without the `.html` your blog page has exactly the same identifier as the blog folder. (identified by: `blog`)
By the Primacy of folders over files the server then opens the `/blog/` folder, but the blog folder doesn't have an index page, and the server (quite rightly) is denying directory listing access.

This is the error you are seeing - your server is stopping you seeing the listing of files in your `/blog/` folder. Forbidden.

Solution: 
- Add an index page to your `/blog/` folder. This can simply be a redirect to any page in the blog folder (so `/blog/index.html` loads `/blog/post1.html`).
- Or you can set the default index page to one that does exist, such as `blog1.html`:

in `/blog/.htaccess`

```
 # Note there is no .html as this is removed by the 
 # htaccess in the folder above. 
 DirectoryIndex post1
```

[Read more about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002439/make-index-html-default-but-allow-index-php-to-be-visited-if-typed-in).

[Abhishek gurjar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41533598/3536236) gives you details on how to improve your current `.htacess` rules, too. But his solution doesn't handle your issue of forbidden access to your `/blogs/` folder index.

Comment: martin ,the htaccess is in root. if op creates a new htaccess in blog folder then the rules wont remove the extension of blog lavel requests.

Comment: `DirectoryIndex post1` would work though? @starkeen I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ $1.html [QSA,L]
```

Please comment or remove previous rule before trying this rule.

In your previous rule you are putting condition that if the request is neither a filename nor a directory than do rewriting to your rule. But the catch is you have blog as a directory which do the exact request to blog directory and i assume you have directory listing disabled that's why it forbidden error.

Above rule check that the requested url is an actual html file than it execute the rule. otherwise if it is a directory then it serve the directory.