# htaccess - Wordpress inside Silverstripe

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, silverstripe

I have a Wordpress install in a subdirectory of a Silverstripe install. I cannot get the front end of the Wordpress site to show due to the rewriting, however the back end works no problem if I append /index.php.

If I try append /index.php to /subdirectory/index.php it redirects back to subdirectory. There are no rules in the WP htaccess so I am thinking Silverstripe isn't liking the extensions.

I tried excluding the entire subdirectory folder by adding this to the Silvestripe site after Rewrite engine:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/.*
```

Not getting it right. Is there a way to allow 'subdirectory' to do its own thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite rules apply to subfolders as well. If you *don't* have an `.htaccess` in your WP subfolder, you should create one and disable URL rewriting for that folder. So, put an `.htaccess` with the following content into your WP folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

Of course you can also define custom rewrite rules… the important thing is, that you have your own `.htaccess`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I had tried this but it would return a 403 error, while the back end still works. Removing RewriteEngine shows a Silverstripe 404 error

Comment: @Craig maybe you don't have index.php as possible index page? Should be fixable with a `DirectoryIndex` setting… http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002439/make-index-html-default-but-allow-index-php-to-be-visited-if-typed-in

Comment: Once again thank you very much! That seems to have sorted out the problem.

Comment: Don't forget to add empty file with name "_manifest_exclude" in your WP subfolder, otherwise Silverstripe will add all WP classes to its manifest which may cause errors in Silverstripe if any of those classes have same names.

Comment: Note that this breaks WP’s “pretty URLs” permalinks.

Answer (score 1):

You should have rules both in the SilverStripe root folder and in the WordPress folder, otherwise WordPress won't run without index.php. Something like this should work (although not 100% sure about the WordPress rules):

**SilverStripe .htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase '/'

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
    RewriteRule .* framework/main.php?url=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Wordpress .htaccess in /wordpress folder**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I had to add these lines to my WP’s `.htaccess` file as well: `DirectoryIndex index.php` and `Options -Indexes`